# What is [__NSCFString base64String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance?

Tags: ios, objective-c

`[__NSCFString base64String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance occurred` While trying to develop push notification.
Here is the entire error log.

```
-[__NSCFString base64String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x165263e0
2015-07-22 15:52:20.441 xxxx[1623:362933] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString base64String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x165263e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x22705fef 0x30da9c8b 0x2270b409 0x22709327 0x22638e78 0x1caa99 0x1c4ba7 0x1bf7ed 0x1bf633 0x1af1d9 0x1ae757 0x1bec3f 0x1c64ed 0x13fdfd 0x260ea37b 0x260eb22d 0x2717d8f3 0x226cb7cb 0x226cb767 0x226c9d69 0x22616201 0x22616013 0x2a0e7201 0x25de2a09 0x145965 0x3135baaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

The following is the source.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    [xxxx startSDKWithAppKey:@"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" host:nil logEnabled:YES sandboxEnabled:NO];

    [xxxx setDelegate:self];
    [xxxx setSPTag:@"xxxx App"];

    [xxxx handleApplication:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

    return YES;
}

#pragma mark APNS notification
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{

 [xxxx handleApplication:application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];

}
```

Eliminating these parts are well executed.

`[xxxx handleApplication:application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];`

Why do not know if this error occurs.
Please tell me how I should be...

Comment: That stacktrace is insufficient.  It's no good to you and no good to us.  Symbolicate it before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you've added the category header files `NSString+Base64.h` and `NSData+Base64.h` but you have not linked-in the corresponding implementation (`.m`) files.

Add `NSString+Base64.m` and `NSData+Base64.m` to the Xcode target and that may well solve your issue.

If, however, those implementation object files are part of a library then you might need to add `-ObjC` to the *Other Linker Flags*.

Answer (score 1):

**unrecognized selector sent** generally occurs when you are calling particular method & that is not there in your code.

Try below things,

- Try to find `base64String` method in your code.
- Add Exception Breakpoint & then run your code.
- Also see if you calling `base64String` on proper object or not.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: base64string can not be found
#import "NSData + Base64.h"
#import "NSString + Base64.h" being used. What I do not know whether the problem .

Comment: Add the required "NSData + Base64.h" to your project. Reference link https://gist.github.com/Abizern/1643491